# Generators of lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, abelian-groups

Consider two lattices $\Lambda_1\subseteq\Lambda_2$ in the complex plane, both generated by two elements, respectively. Is it always possible to find generators $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of $\Lambda_2$ such that $n\alpha$ and $m\beta$ are generators of $\Lambda_1$ for some integers $m$ and $n$?

---

This question came up in a course about Riemann surfaces, in which we briefly studied the projection $\pi$ of the torus $\mathbb C/\Lambda_1$ onto the torus $\mathbb C/\Lambda_2$. If the above is true, the degree of this map $\pi$ would be $mn$.

It is clear that the claim does not hold for *any* generators $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of $\Lambda_2$. For instance, take $\Lambda_2=\alpha\mathbb Z+\beta\mathbb Z$ for $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=\mathrm i$, and $\Lambda_2=2\mathbb Z+(1+\mathrm i)\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Note that this reduces to a problem in pure algebra, because you can always assume that $\Lambda_2 = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$ (just apply a real linear transformation that takes $\Lambda_2$ to $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z = 1 \mathbb Z + i \mathbb Z$).